# Angular 2: How to call a function after get a response from subscribe http.post

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, subscribe

I need to call a method after get the data from the http post request

**service: request.service.TS**

```
get_categories(number){
 this.http.post( url, body, {headers: headers, withCredentials:true})
    .subscribe( 
      response => {
        this.total = response.json();

      }, error => {
    }
  ); 

}
```

**component: categories.TS**

```
search_categories() {

this.get_categories(1);
//I need to call a Method here after get the data from response.json() !! e.g.: send_catagories();
}
```

Only works if I change to:

**service: request.service.TS**

```
get_categories(number){
 this.http.post( url, body, {headers: headers, withCredentials:true})
    .subscribe( 
      response => {
        this.total = response.json();
        this.send_catagories(); //here works fine

      }, error => {
    }
  ); 

}
```

But I need to call the method `send_catagories()` inside of component after call `this.get_categories(1);` like this

component: categories.TS

```
search_categories() {

this.get_categories(1);
this.send_catagories(response);
}
```

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `send_catagories()` also using an observable? If yes, you need to chain the observable from get_categories() to the one in send_categories() with the `.mergeMap()` operator. Let me know if you need help with the syntax.

Comment: send_catagories() is not using observable, please show me the syntax: return this.http.post( url, body, {headers: headers, withCredentials:true})
        .subscribe( 
          response => { this.total_page = response.json();return this.total_page;        
          }, .share()
      ); 

    }
then this.get_category(1).subscribe(response=> {
      this.callfunc();
});

Comment: Got it. I have posted an answer with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Update your `get_categories()` method to **return** the total (wrapped in an observable):

```ts
// Note that .subscribe() is gone and I've added a return.
get_categories(number) {
  return this.http.post( url, body, {headers: headers, withCredentials:true})
    .map(response => response.json());
}
```

In `search_categories()`, you can subscribe the observable returned by `get_categories()` (or you could keep transforming it by chaining more RxJS operators):

```ts
// send_categories() is now called after get_categories().
search_categories() {
  this.get_categories(1)
    // The .subscribe() method accepts 3 callbacks
    .subscribe(
      // The 1st callback handles the data emitted by the observable.
      // In your case, it's the JSON data extracted from the response.
      // That's where you'll find your total property.
      (jsonData) => {
        this.send_categories(jsonData.total);
      },
      // The 2nd callback handles errors.
      (err) => console.error(err),
      // The 3rd callback handles the "complete" event.
      () => console.log("observable complete")
    );
}
```

Note that you **only subscribe ONCE**, at the end.

Like I said in the comments, the `.subscribe()` method of any observable accepts 3 callbacks like this:

```ts
obs.subscribe(
  nextCallback,
  errorCallback,
  completeCallback
);
```

They must be passed in this order. You don't have to pass all three. Many times only the `nextCallback` is implemented:

```ts
obs.subscribe(nextCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks, Thanks, Thanks! it is working perfect!  just two question,1) inside this.send_categories(total){ this.myNewTotal= total } How I can ectract the data (responde.json) from "total" parameter?  2)  i have added "error" to the syntax: .map(response => response.json()), error => {
        } ); if I need call this.send_categories(total) only in error case, how I can subscribe to error ?

Comment: Hmm. Based on your previous code, I thought `response.json()` **WAS** the total. What I mean is, I named the variable `total` but it contains whatever is in `response.json()`; you can name this variable whatever you want. I've updated my answer to reflect that better and also to show you how to handle the error.

Comment: I may be missing the point of the third argument in subscribe but I am wondering if you can invoke a method to complete the callback?

Comment: Oftentimes the two callbacks are synonymous. Take an HTTP request for instance. When the server returns the data, the `nextCallback` is invoked, and then immediately after the `completeCallback`. But in a different situation (e.g. a chat system), the `nextCallback` could be invoked multiple times (e.g. for each chat notification) and the `completeCallback` could never be invoked.

Comment: If you created an observable with `Observable.create()`, you can complete it with `observer.complete()`. If you have a Subject, you can call `subject.complete()`. Finally, some operators trigger the completion of the observable, like `obs.take(1)` which completes the observable after one value has been emitted.

Comment: the best explanation ever.

Answer (score 10):

You can add a callback function to your list of get_category(...) parameters.

Ex:

```
 get_categories(number, callback){
 this.http.post( url, body, {headers: headers, withCredentials:true})
    .subscribe( 
      response => {
        this.total = response.json();
        callback(); 

      }, error => {
    }
  ); 

}
```

And then you can just call get_category(...) like this:

```
this.get_category(1, name_of_function);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try. But my idea is use something more proffesional to catch the response. Eg: get_category(1).then or an observable but i dont know how to do that

Comment: There's nothing unprofessional about using callback functions but suit yourself

Comment: In my opinion, passing in a callback to a service when using observables is not a good pattern. As Louis alluded to, it makes additional logic and error handling ugly.

Comment: @RobM I just wanted to say that you're right. While rewriting a co-workers application, I went to callback hell and back and I now see the error in my ways!

Answer (score 6):

You can code as a lambda expression as the third parameter(on complete) to the subscribe method. Here I re-set the departmentModel variable to the default values.

```
saveData(data:DepartmentModel){
  return this.ds.sendDepartmentOnSubmit(data).
  subscribe(response=>this.status=response,
   ()=>{},
   ()=>this.departmentModel={DepartmentId:0});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this be using a new `Subject` too:

**Typescript:**

```
let subject = new Subject();

get_categories(...) {
   this.http.post(...).subscribe( 
      (response) => {
         this.total = response.json();
         subject.next();
      }
   ); 

   return subject; // can be subscribed as well 
}

get_categories(...).subscribe(
   (response) => {
     // ...
   }
);
```

Comment: @Pratik what do you mean by that?

Comment: it means 1st statement let subject = new Subject();  gives error as there is no subject class.

Comment: @Pratik you need rxjs for that

Comment: keep mentioning that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
get_categories(number){
 return this.http.post( url, body, {headers: headers, withCredentials:true})
      .map(t=>  {
          this.total = t.json();
          return total;
      }).share();
  );     
}
```

then

```
this.get_category(1).subscribe(t=> {
      this.callfunc();
});
```

Comment: Yes!, this is what I want, how I can keep the old syntax without ".map"?, eg : return this.http.post( url, body, {headers: headers, withCredentials:true})
    .subscribe( 
      response => {
        this.total = response.json(); return total;
      }).share();

Comment: (173,69): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.

Comment: Why do you want the original syntax? FRP is about combining streams to create one meaningful observable that can be subscribed to.

Comment: @pixelbits I get an error message that `.share does not exist on type Observable<any>` and also should `return total` not be `return this.total`? Just trying to figure this code out seeing that I am struggling with something similar.